# Does GetInt() automatically create \n outputs here?

Tags: c

Suppose I have code that asks the user to give 2 integers, and when the user give the integers, the program prints the sum.

```
int main(void)

{ 
printf("Please give me an int: "); 
int x = GetInt();

printf("Please give me an int: "); 
int y = GetInt();

printf("%d\n", x + y); 
}
```

When I run the program, all three printf's appear on separate lines.

**My question:** What I don't understand is why the first two printf's do not require \n in order to move to a new line, yet the third printf does require \n.

Comment: Your GetInt() function is probably creating the new line with user input.

Comment: Depends what `GetInt()` is doing.

Comment: Can you post the code for `GetInt()`?

Comment: if you're `GetInt()` is reading from stdin (using `scanf`) then the shell is adding the newline when you press Return.  try adding two `printf`s one after another without a newline or scanf in between

Comment: You guys are right; it's the GetInt() that's doing it. It just didn't enter my brain at first. Thanks!

Comment: You should accept the answer (below) if you think it's correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\n` for the first two is provided by the user when they hit enter after inputting their number.